# Не запускается Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Доброго всем.
Проблема - не запускается AS. Ошибок никаких нет, даже процесс не стартует. Качал с оф сайта. Переменная объявлена. ОС - win7 x86. Что может быть? Разумеется без переустановки винды (пока этот вариант не рассматривается).
П.С. Комп без инета
Спасибо

Comment: смотрите логи в `Event Viewer` (Просмотр событий Windows)

Comment: как вы ее запускаете? экзешник 32-ух битный *studio.exe* стартуете?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, проблема в том, что имя пользователя Windows (т. е. и имя папки пользовтеля) состоит не из латинских букв. У меня программа запустилась только от имени другого пользователя (с именем из латинских букв). Может, дело было не только в этом.